# How to call the selected item from one layout to another layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new to android java coding. i have did my java class and xml layout, but i'm stuck at view. I don't know how to make the selected item from menu.xml to be shown on view.xml layout? Here is my coding for menu and view.

This is my menu.java .

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
 
 Button btnorder; 
 Button btnback;
 Button btnlinkcart;
 
ArrayList<String> checked_item = new ArrayList();

    
 CheckBox pizza_large;
 CheckBox pizza_medium;
 CheckBox pizza_personal;
 CheckBox Chicken_wings;
 CheckBox garlic_bread;
 CheckBox drink_large;
 CheckBox drink_medium;
 
 
 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        
  btnlinkcart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  btnback  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);  
  pizza_large = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
  pizza_medium = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
  pizza_personal = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
  Chicken_wings = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
  garlic_bread = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
  drink_large = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
  drink_medium = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
  
  //TODO:repeat for the rest
 
// protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//  setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        

  
   // back button click event
        btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    
   }
        });
        
      //array to store what item is checked
        // Link to Cart Screen
          btnlinkcart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View view) {
            if(pizza_large.isChecked())
             checked_item.add("pizza_large");
            else if (pizza_medium.isChecked())
             checked_item.add("pizza_medium");
            else if (pizza_personal.isChecked())
             checked_item.add("pizza_personal");
            else if (Chicken_wings.isChecked())
             checked_item.add("Chicken_wings");
            else if (garlic_bread.isChecked())
             checked_item.add("garlic_bread");
            else if (drink_large.isChecked())
             checked_item.add("drink_large");
            else if (drink_medium.isChecked())
             checked_item.add("drink_medium");
            

            
           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
              ViewActivity.class);
            
            //checked_item ArrayList is bundled
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putStringArrayList("item_checked", checked_item);
            i.putExtra("data", data);
            
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
           }
          });
    }
        


}
```

This is menu.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Back" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Pizza (Large) RM30.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Pizza (Mediume) RM20.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Pizza (Personal) RM10.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Chicken Wings RM12.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Garlic Bread RM6.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Soft Drink (Large) RM5.00" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Soft Drink (Medium) RM4.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is view.java

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewActivity extends Activity {
 
 Button btnconfirm;
 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.cart);
        
  Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
  ArrayList<String> checked_item = new ArrayList();;
  if (data != null){
   checked_item = data.getStringArrayList("item_checked");
  }
  

  
  btnconfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  

  
  // Link to Cart Screen
   btnconfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
     Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
       ConfirmActivity.class);
     startActivity(i);
     finish();
    }
   });
 }

}
```

This is view.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper" >

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="MultiAutoCompleteTextView" >

        <requestFocus />
    </MultiAutoCompleteTextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Confirm" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it look at my comments and make sure you know ansswers to these questions. Also i would have used a textView over a multiAutocompleteTextView.

```
public class ViewActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnconfirm;
    // lets get handle to TextView element defined in your xml with id multiAutoCompleteTextView1
    TextView myTextView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cart);

        // find the view and add it to the handle
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);
        Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<String> checked_item = new ArrayList();;
        if (data != null){
            checked_item = data.getStringArrayList("item_checked");
            // set text in the text view that was grabbed from the budle.
           // search what are bundles how to pass data from one activity to another
           // what are intents
           // how to start an activity

             myTextView.setText(checked_item);
        }



        btnconfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



        // Link to Cart Screen
        btnconfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ConfirmActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```